# List of deprecated features for PostgreSQL 8 to 13

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, deprecation

I'm going to upgrade several PostgreSQL 8 databases to version 13. The people I work for come from SQL Server. I've been looking for a tool similar to "DMA", specifically the part that lists deprecated features and "breaking changes". They want a report to estimate times. They love reports. Docx's and xlsx's everywhere.

Comment: As side note: are you aware that before Postgres 10, the version numbering was a bit different? "Version 8" covers 5 major version (8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4). But there is no tool that will show you those things. You will have to read the release notes for all 11 versions you haven't kept up with. This is another good reason to upgrade early: the pain is much smaller and it's usually much less work.

Comment: I know. I started with 9.1.
That's what I was afraid of. I've been reading the documentation and listing all the deprecated features.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might be quicker just running your queries and seeing what fails! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each PostgreSQL version has a section “Migration to Version xy” section in the base release part of appendix E of the documentation. This is where the incompatibilities to the previous release are enumerated. [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.13.4) is a link to this for version 12.

You have to read through all of these sections for all of the base releases between 8.x and 13. Sure, that's a lot of changes, but that's to be expected for such a jump. My tip is not to spend too much time with this huge list, most of which you won't understand. Rather, invest a lot of time in testing.